# More than one important path for .NET Process

Tags: c#, process

In a project I'm currently working on, I am starting an external process. However, the external process is the EXE of a complex program which loads current-user information from a user folder. The desktop shortcut for the program resolves the matter by setting the "Target:" parameter to `X:\exepath\prgm.exe` and setting the "Start In" parameter to the user's path, `X:\exepath\users\username`.

I currently launch the process like this:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo( "X:\exepath\prgm.exe" );
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "X:\exepath\users\username";
p.Start();
while (!p.HasExited) { }
```

However, when the process is started, the program it launches ends up looking for all resources in the `WorkingDirectory` instead of pulling user content from that folder and all other content from the directory the EXE resides in. <strike>This suggests that `Working Directory` and the system shortcut "Start In:" parameter behave differently.</strike>

Is there any way to mimic that behavior with a C# Process? Alternatively, is it possible to create a shortcut in C#, which I could then start with my Process invocation?

Please let me know if more info would be helpful.

EDIT -

After some more trial and error, I decided to use [WSH to create a shortcut](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial125_Create-shortcuts-with-a-.NET-application.html)  and run it. WSH uses the name WorkingDirectory for the value of the "Start In:" parameter. It behaves identically under the hood as the execution of the process in my code above. I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my problem, which was not related to the creation of a Process after all. In fact, the root cause is a little embarrassing, but potentially educational, so I'll provide an explanation.

The code I posted in the OP was sample code to illustrate the problem. In my actual project, I was retrieving the `ExePath` and the `UserPath` from registry keys. The project is a Chooser tool to switch between multiple installed versions of the third-party software, and reads/edits these registry keys to do its work.

When I wrote the code that *writes* to the registry, I used `DirectoryInfo.FullPath`, which returned `"X:\ExePath"` instead of `"X:\ExePath\"`. This made the program unable to find the files it needed from the ExePath folder, looking for X:\ExePathsettings.inf" instead of "X:\ExePath\settings.inf". I inserted trailing backslashes to my code and to the existing registry entires, and everything worked just fine.

Lesson learned: Always check your path values very, very carefully.

Comment: Better lesson: Use `System.IO.Path.Combine()`.

Comment: @Joel: I do use Path.Combine quite a lot, but wasn't aware until now that DirectoryInfo's FullPath property didn't add a trailing backslash. Now that I know, I can use them both in conjunction to greater benefit. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1):

The difference is likely due to using a Shell Process to execute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx

> The WorkingDirectory property behaves
>   differently when UseShellExecute is
>   true than when UseShellExecute is
>   false. When UseShellExecute is true,
>   the WorkingDirectory property
>   specifies the location of the
>   executable. If WorkingDirectory is an
>   empty string, the current directory is
>   understood to contain the executable.
>
> When UseShellExecute is false, the
>   WorkingDirectory property is not used
>   to find the executable. Instead, it is
>   used by the process that is started
>   and has meaning only within the
>   context of the new process.

I suspect if you set p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute to false it may behave as you want.

Comment: Or to .True? I thought it defaulted to false in .net, and shortcuts just used ShellExecute?

Comment: Booleans on .NET do default to false, but this property doesn't, via the link: "true to use the shell when starting the process; otherwise, the process is created directly from the executable file. The default is true."

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried both values and neither one yielded a change in outcome. One of the tools in the external process uses an INF file in the user path and multiple INFs in the EXE path, but with the code above, plus either value in `UseShellExecute`, the tool in question gives the error: "Can't open X:\exepath\users\username\file.inf", where file.inf is the file it should be seeking in exepath